# DIfference in Compilation of CoffeScipt Files to JS

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript

While compiling the coffeescript files from ruby script,

Sample code from my application,

```
$( () =>
  rest_api_login((login_ok, userName, userRoles) ->
    console.log("login_ok #{login_ok}, userName #{userName}, roles [#{userRoles.join(", ")}]")
    vcm.app.userName = userName
    vcm.app.userRoles = userRoles
    vcm.app.defaultClassifications = []
    initialize_templates((loaded_templates) ->
      console.log("loaded_templates", loaded_templates)
      vcm.app.main_application()
    )
  )
)
```

So, there is a difference, when compiling it into js. 
Last committed code was about 2-3 years ago and the developer are not in the company who compiled the last file.
There are few changes in compilation, for ex: a!=b is compiled now as !(a==b), so nothing major just the way of compilation.

So, in my compiled file, the output js file is:

```
$(function() {
    return rest_api_login(function(login_ok, userName, userRoles) {
      console.log("login_ok " + login_ok + ", userName " + userName + ", roles [" + (userRoles.join(", ")) + "]");
      vcm.app.userName = userName;
      vcm.app.userRoles = userRoles;
      vcm.app.defaultClassifications = [];
      return initialize_templates(function(loaded_templates) {
        console.log("loaded_templates", loaded_templates);
        return vcm.app.main_application();
      });
    });
  });
```

and earlier compiled file has the following js:

```
$((function(_this) {
    return function() {
      return rest_api_login(function(login_ok, userName, userRoles) {
        console.log("login_ok " + login_ok + ", userName " + userName + ", roles [" + (userRoles.join(", ")) + "]");
        vcm.app.userName = userName;
        vcm.app.userRoles = userRoles;
        vcm.app.defaultClassifications = [];
        return initialize_templates(function(loaded_templates) {
          console.log("loaded_templates", loaded_templates);
          return vcm.app.main_application();
        });
      });
    };
  })(this));
```

So my js does not have the **return** statement and the corresponding **this** keyword which is present in the earlier compiled file.

And this applies to over my complete js file which has over 15000 lines,

1. Will this type of effect cause hindrance in the functionality of the application?
2. What if I want to generate the same js generated before?

I tried compiling it with almost all the versions of gem, **coffee-script**, current compiled version is from 2.2.0. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that your new code uses a [fat arrow `=>`](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow), whereas the old one used a normal function declaration with `->`. With a fat arrow, `this` of a newly declared function is bound to be the `this` of the outer scope. It's really helpful with callbacks.

In this case fat arrow won't have any effect since `this` isn't referenced and the callback passed to `rest_api_login` defines a new scope. It's unnecessary and you should just replace the `=>` with `->`. This will generate the original code (sans minor language changes).

Comment: The main problem is the two return functions, and I don't want to change the fat arrow because it has always been like this, so it is not an issue, although I understand what you are saying.
Thanks

Comment: The second return function (the one binding inner `_this` to outer `this`) is unnecessary and the only difference. The earlier compiled file was with a fat arrow, yours is not (or it has been optimized away). C.f. https://gist.github.com/kba/db5b4495f9a03664e3cb8c68cb7bfd8d